# How to remove column headers in dataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, epplus

I have generic list and I'm converting that to `DataTable`

Then I'm generating columns with the properties of the list and adding rows to it, Now I want to remove the column headers fro the table

This is my code for Converting `List` To `DataTable`

```
    public class ListtoDataTableConverter
    {
        public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
             //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

The result for the above code is

```
    Name                  Age
   ---------------------------------
     A                    22
     B                    23
```

Now I want to have the output without the Name and Age.

How can I remove them

Comment: *Well,* you don't have to remove column names/headers from the `DataTable` instead remove them from your displaying control, like `Grid`

Comment: I have to write it to excel, so I have to remove it

Comment: I don't know exactly *how*, but there must be a way in the API to ignore header columns while writing to excel. Modify your question to state that, also specify the excel api you are using.

Comment: I'm using **EPPLUS** to write to excel

Comment: If you want to remove the first row of a datatable:  dataTable.Rows[0].delete()

Comment: It deletes the row    `A             22` but not the headers

Answer (score 2):

No real way of "removing" column headers from a table - it is a table after all.  But why not just tell epplus to suppress the outputting of the header row with `.LoadFromDataTable(dtdata, false)` - note the `false` as the second paramter `PrintHeaders'.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ListToDataTableConverter()
{
    //Use a func for demonstrative purposes
    Func<List<NameAgeObject>, DataTable> ToDataTable = (items) =>
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(NameAgeObject).Name);
        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(NameAgeObject).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (NameAgeObject item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    };

    var itemlist = new List<NameAgeObject>
    {
        new NameAgeObject {Name = "A", Age = 22},
        new NameAgeObject {Name = "B", Age = 23},
        new NameAgeObject {Name = "C", Age = 24},
        new NameAgeObject {Name = "D", Age = 25},
        new NameAgeObject {Name = "E", Age = 26},
    };

    var dtdata = ToDataTable(itemlist);


    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dtdata, false);
        package.Save();
    }

}
```

If it is a very big table you might see a performance problem with `LoadFromDataTable` in which case you can manually write to the worksheet by hitting the individual cells in excel.  Here you ap the datatable by row/column and simply skip any writing of column info.